# Pass multiple urls to itemview in recyclerview using multiple onclick listeners

Tags: android, url, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

In my onBindViewholder, I am passing onclickListener to itemview in recycler view. Itemview consists of an array with image and text;
**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;
    private AdView mAdView2;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView firstrecyclerView;

    private RecyclerView thirdrecyclerView;
    ArrayList<itemModel> items;

    String[] iconName = {"ABP Sanjha","Breaking News Punjab","Republic Bharat", "Al Jazeera","DW News","Sky News","Indus Live","CNA","RT News"};

    //cannel icons and names
    private String[] channelnames={"PTC Punjabi","Chakde TV","T-Series Punjabi", "9X Tashan", "Zee Punjabi" };
    private int[] channelimages={R.drawable.ptcpunjabi, R.drawable.chakde, R.drawable.tseries, R.drawable.ninex, R.drawable.zeepunjabi};
    private String[] channelID={"UCHJW1_0oPzYZl89wX_jhrgA","UCaT-WGdJLyEDnxZPAKRTbqQ","UCJMSoNjSKRARSIJM3GymRjQ","UCrET5fR2NAUTO2Xp12G0l8A", "UCYF_LfBBxkFBEgaSCNrqW3w"};

    private List<channel> channelList=new ArrayList<>();

    //youtube player fragment
    private YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX youTubePlayerFragment;
    private ArrayList<String> youtubeVideoArrayList;
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        generateDummyVideoList();
        initializeYoutubePlayer();
        setUpRecyclerView();
        populateRecyclerView();
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        mAdView2 = findViewById(R.id.adView2);
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView2.loadAd(adRequest2);

    }

    /**
     * initialize youtube player via Fragment and get instance of YoutubePlayer
     */
    private void initializeYoutubePlayer() {

        youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);
        if (youTubePlayerFragment == null)
            return;
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                                boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    youTubePlayer = player;
                    //set the player style default
                    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                    //cue the 1st video by default
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubeVideoArrayList.get(0));
                    youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

                //print or show error if initialization failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Youtube Player View initialization failed");
            }
        });
    }

     // setup the recycler view here
         private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        firstrecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.first_recycler_view);
        firstrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        //Horizontal direction recycler view
        LinearLayoutManager firstlinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        firstrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(firstlinearLayoutManager);
        firstrecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        for (int i = 0; i < iconName.length; i++) {
            itemModel itemModel = new itemModel(iconName[i], youtubeVideoArrayList.get(i));
            items.add(itemModel);
        }


        thirdrecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.third_recycler_view);
        thirdrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        channelList=new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayoutManager thirdlinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        thirdrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(thirdlinearLayoutManager);
        for (int i=0;i < channelnames.length;i++){
            channel channel=new channel(channelnames[i],channelimages[i]);
            channelList.add(channel);
        }
      }

     //populate the recycler view and implement the click event here
     private void populateRecyclerView() {
        final CustomAdapter adapterf = new CustomAdapter(this, items);
        firstrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterf);

        //set click event
        firstrecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewOnClickListener(this, new RecyclerViewOnClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                if (youTubePlayerFragment != null && youTubePlayer != null) {
                    //update selected position
                    adapterf.setSelectedPosition(position);
                    //load selected video
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubeVideoArrayList.get(position));
                }
            }
        }));



         channeladpater channeladpater=new channeladpater(channelList);
         thirdrecyclerView.setAdapter(channeladpater);
     }

    //method to generate dummy array list of videos
    private void generateDummyVideoList() {
        youtubeVideoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        //get the video id array from strings.xml
        String[] videoIDArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.video_id_array);

        //add all videos to array list
        Collections.addAll(youtubeVideoArrayList, videoIDArray);

    }
}
```

Now I tried to open another activity when itemview is clicked in this way;
**channeladapter** class;

```
public class channeladpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<channeladpater.Channelviewholder> {
    private List<channel> channelList;
    Context ctx;

    public channeladpater(List<channel> channelList) {
        this.channelList=channelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Channelviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
        return new Channelviewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Channelviewholder holder, int position)
    {
        final channel channel=channelList.get(position);
        holder.channelname.setText(channel.getChannelname());
        holder.channelimage.setImageResource(channel.getChannelimage());
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {
                final String[] channelID={"UCHJW1_0oPzYZl89wX_jhrgA","UCaT-WGdJLyEDnxZPAKRTbqQ","UCJMSoNjSKRARSIJM3GymRjQ","UCrET5fR2NAUTO2Xp12G0l8A", "UCYF_LfBBxkFBEgaSCNrqW3w"};
                Intent intent=MainActivity2.newIntent(v.getContext(), channelID);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return channelList.size();
    }

    public static class Channelviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView channelname;
        public CircleImageView channelimage;
        ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

        Channelviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
           this.channelname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
            this.channelimage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            this.itemClickListener.onItemClickListener(v,getLayoutPosition());
        }
        public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener ic){
            this.itemClickListener=ic;
        }

    }
}
}
```

the new activity start is basically the list of videos fetched using youtube data api;
MainActivity2

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity { 

        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        ArrayList<VideoDetails> videoDetailsoArrayList;
        public static String CHANNEL_ID_EXTRA = "channel_id_extra";
        public static Intent newIntent(Context context, String[] channelID) {
        return new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class).putExtra(CHANNEL_ID_EXTRA, channelID);
    }

        String API_Key = "AIzaSyA1_spJ4XGWOCekBLCsSAgWderHHl_46m0";
        private String[] channelID={"UCHJW1_0oPzYZl89wX_jhrgA","UCaT-WGdJLyEDnxZPAKRTbqQ","UCJMSoNjSKRARSIJM3GymRjQ","UCrET5fR2NAUTO2Xp12G0l8A", "UCYF_LfBBxkFBEgaSCNrqW3w"};
        String url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId="+ Arrays.toString(channelID) +"&maxResults=50&sort=date&key=AIzaSyA1_spJ4XGWOCekBLCsSAgWderHHl_46m0";
        adapter adapter;
        Context ctx;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
            final String channelID = getIntent().getStringExtra(CHANNEL_ID_EXTRA);
            recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.listView);
            videoDetailsoArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
            adapter=new adapter(MainActivity2.this,videoDetailsoArrayList);

            displayVideos();
        }
        private void displayVideos ()
        {
            RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (jsonObject1.has("id")){
                                JSONObject jsonVideoId=jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                                if (jsonVideoId.has("kind")){
                                    if(jsonVideoId.getString("kind").equals("youtube#video")) {
                                        JSONObject jsonObjectSnippet = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet");
                                        JSONObject jsonObjectDefault = jsonObjectSnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium");

                                        String video_id = jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");

                                        VideoDetails vd = new VideoDetails();

                                        vd.setVideoId(video_id);
                                        vd.setTitle(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("title"));
                                        vd.setDescription(jsonObjectSnippet.getString("description"));
                                        vd.setUrl(jsonObjectDefault.getString("url"));

                                        videoDetailsoArrayList.add(vd);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                    adapter= new adapter(getApplicationContext(),videoDetailsoArrayList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
```

Now I am trying to change the **channelID** from the String url of MainActivity2 such that when itemview with String *channelnames* "PTC Punjabi" is clicked, the MainActivity is loaded with *channelID* "UCHJW1_0oPzYZl89wX_jhrgA", when *channelnames* "Chakde Tv" is clicked, the **MainActivity2** is loaded with
*channelID* "UCaT-WGdJLyEDnxZPAKRTbqQ" and so on. but I dont understand how to pass the list of **channelId** to MainActivity2?
Should I declare **channelId** array in MainActivity?. Please somebody guide me in this step. I know the solution is small as I have seen tutorials on button activities but I cant understand passing url to other activity.
**channel** model class

```
public class channel {
    String channelname;
    int channelimage;

    public channel(String channelname, int channelimage) {
        this.channelname = channelname;
        this.channelimage = channelimage;
    }

    public String getChannelname() {
        return channelname;
    }

    public int getChannelimage() {
        return channelimage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: it's not a good practice to create `Intent` somewhere else then Activity of which intent your are creating.
So you need to add static method in your MainActivity2:

```
public static String CHANNEL_ID_EXTRA = "channel_id_extra";
public static Intent newIntent(Context context, String channelID) {
    return new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class).putExtra(CHANNEL_ID_EXTRA, channelID);
}
```

After that you can get this ID in `onCreate()` method by :

```
final String channelId = getIntent().getStringExtra(CHANNEL_ID_EXTRA);
```

And now in Holder: **EDITED HERE**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Channelviewholder holder, int position) {
    final channel channel=channelList.get(position);
    holder.channelname.setText(channel.getChannelname());
    holder.channelimage.setImageResource(channel.getChannelimage());
    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {
            final String channelID= channelList.get(position);
            Intent intent=MainActivity2.newIntent(v.getContext(), channelID);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: but I have a list of channelID..How to declare them beforehand so that each item of that string is assigned based on the click

Comment: `PTC punjabi
UCHJW1_0oPzYZl89wX_jhrgA

Chakde Tv
UCaT-WGdJLyEDnxZPAKRTbqQ

T-series punjabi
UCJMSoNjSKRARSIJM3GymRjQ

9x tashan
UCrET5fR2NAUTO2Xp12G0l8A

zee punjabi
UCYF_LfBBxkFBEgaSCNrqW3w`   this is the list I want to pass on 5 separate clicks

Comment: this is not assiging any ID

Comment: @summyiaharis how do you create the list of Items for your Adapter?

Comment: `   holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View v, int position) {
                final String[] channelID={"UCHJW1_0oPzYZl89wX_jhrgA","UCaT-WGdJLyEDnxZPAKRTbqQ","UCJMSoNjSKRARSIJM3GymRjQ","UCrET5fR2NAUTO2Xp12G0l8A", "UCYF_LfBBxkFBEgaSCNrqW3w"};
                Intent intent=MainActivity2.newIntent(v.getContext(), channelID);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
        });`

Comment: Check edits in my question. its a model Class channel

Comment: its giving error `error: incompatible types: channel cannot be converted to String
                final String channelID=channelList.get(position);
                                                      ^`

Comment: @summyiaharis what if you try `final String channelID= channelList[position]` ?

Comment: `Array type expected; found: 'java.util.List<com.currentmedia.punjabinews.Models.channel>'`

Comment: I have tried declaring channelID in constructor as well but its not working